# Is there a way for a Android app to return directly to the activity it started with?

Tags: android

I'm just learning Android programming.  The way I understand it is that the services work like a stack, Is there a way for a activity to return to the first activity that started the app, instead of just the previous one.

Example, say I have 4 activities, a,b,c,d.  Is there a way for activity d to have a button that would bring up activity a?? Instead of activity d going to c, and c going back to b???

Comment: possible duplicate of [finish() activity twice in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808223/finish-activity-twice-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start again activity *a*, but using a flag in your intent:

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

From [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT):

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.

Using this, you'll reuse the instance of activity *a* already running, instead of starting a new one. Note that doing this, the instances of activities *b*, *c* and *d* will remain in the back stack (now after activity *a*).

Otherwise, if you want to finish this activities (and remove them from the back stack) you can start activity *a* (from *d*) with [this other flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

**EDIT**: this is a good resource to read, if you haven't did it yet:
[Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.  You simply code an intent for activity a to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
finish():
```

You will be reverted to the main page

or else write an intent pointing to a

Answer (score 0):

You can send information to different `Activities` via `Intents`.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AvitivityName.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Don't forget to add your `Activities` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Here's some tutorial on Android `Intents`:

1. [**how to use Android intents**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html).
2. [**how to switch to another activity with a button click**](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/).